# What's the meaning of two horizontal or vertical rectangles in the layers panel?

Tags: layers, tools, figma

What's the meaning of two horizontal or vertical rectangles in the layers panel? Like in the screenshot below.

[image: Two horizontal and two vertical rectangles in the layers panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the [Auto Layout frames](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040451373-Create-dynamic-designs-with-Auto-Layout) - the icon represents the direction the Auto Layout frame will flow:

- Horizontal: objects flow as a row
- Vertical: objects flow as a column

[image: sample image from Figma.com]